# DNS and Google Cloud Platform load balancer

Tags: dns, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I am trying to use google cloud platform for the first time and seem a bit hung up on something that I would think should be easy.

I created an instance group and am trying to create a load balancer to point both http and https traffic to that instance group.  When I configured the front end for the load balancer I added both http and https; however, doing so created two ip addresses and I can only point the DNS to one of these records.  I am assuming I am just missing a simple step, as I am used to working with AWS.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Think I answered my own question.  I just pointed to the https ip address and both http and https requests ended up working.